# Laravel Api Route with namespace failed

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

i have a small crud frontend to store information. The frontend controller is called `ShowsController`. And i want to get alle Shows from the api.

So my `routes/web.php` contains:

```
Route::resource('shows', 'ShowsController');
```

Thats perfect and worked really well.

My `routes/api.php` contains:

```
Route::resource('shows', 'ShowsController', ['only' => ['index']]);
```

The route `/api/shows` should give me the shows as json.
to decide frontend and api i put the `ShowsController` into `Controllers/Api folder`

The `Controllers/Api/ShowsController` contains:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Show;

class ShowsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return response()
            ->json(Show::all())->withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'text/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'
            ]);
    }
}
```

And i also changed the `RouteServiceProvider` to:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'namespace' => 'Api',
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
```

But the command `php artisan route:list` gives me an exception:

> [ReflectionException]
>     Class Api\ShowsController does not exist

Why is laravel not finding the defined ShowsController in the api directory?

Comment: have You try : composer dump-autoload?

Comment: @LorenzoBerti yes, i did before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what version of Laravel you are using, but in 5.4, I have, by default, this method:

```php
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

It could work if you replace `namespace($this->namespace)` by `namespace($this->namespace . '\Api')`.

Comment: thats worked. and now i see why. with my api namespace i cutted `App\Http\Controllers` so the autoloader is searching my controller at `/Api` and not at `/App/Http/Controllers/Api`. thank you